# Uncaught TypeError: e.map is not a function after updating to angular 4

Tags: angular

after updating to angular 4 i getting this errormessaging. i dont know where it comes from and i dont understand what exactly chrome will say to me.

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.map is not a function
at t.parameters (vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:51)
at e.parameters (vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:51)
at t.getDependenciesMetadata (vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:120)
at t.getTypeMetadata (vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:120)
at vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:120
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at t.getProvidersMetadata (vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:120)
at t.getNgModuleMetadata (vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:120)
at vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:120
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
t.parameters    @   vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:51
e.parameters    @   vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:51
t.getDependenciesMetadata   @   vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:120
t.getTypeMetadata   @   vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:120
(anonymous) @   vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:120
t.getProvidersMetadata  @   vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:120
t.getNgModuleMetadata   @   vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:120
(anonymous) @   vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:120
t.getNgModuleMetadata   @   vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:120
t._compileComponents    @   vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:122
t._compileModuleAndComponents   @   vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:121
t.compileModuleAsync    @   vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:121
e._bootstrapModuleWithZone  @   vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:59
e.bootstrapModule   @   vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:59
bootApplication @   boot-client.ts:17
t.invokeTask    @   vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:201
n.runTask   @   vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:201
invoke  @   vendor.js?v=ieYBBzkkpOeg5eS28e4kMG5hTCbhSNE8T-M4VYaekSA:201
```

Comment: Are you using Angular CLI?

Comment: I think so. In my package.json i found this row.
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.5",

Comment: Run the app with `ng serve` so you can see an unminified version to help you figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First save your code somewhere.

It seems have angular cli v4 installed, otherwise do in your terminal:

```
cd yourDevelopmentRootDirectory

npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

once finished:

```
ng new yourProjectName
```

this will create an angular4 starter project.

Serve the application at the port localhost:4200:

```
cd yourProjectName
ng serve --open
```

For your reference : https://angular.io/guide/quickstart and https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Now, copy for saved project code (./src/app) back in yourProjectName directory, and check if it's compiling.

Comment: Ok. i tried this. If i copy the old to the new i get an error 'cannot find name require'.

Comment: If i tried the new to the old i get the same error.

Comment: First, see my update please. Does the starter project run correctly? If so, do npm install inside the project directory. If it doesn' help, try to not copy your code but update the starter project file by file. It asks for some work but it will be profitable to optimize your code too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I tried it again. it is a little bit complex. With your example i create an angular app only. But my project is an asp.core with angular. The angular only app works fine at start. I removed all my customizings in my ClientApp-Folder, its the same of src\app. but the error is the same. 
I see in the angular2 app the tsconfig.json but in my visual studio project i don't find the file.